# how to set different color to routerLink , on Chrome its white is same as background so text is not visible

Tags: angular, hyperlink, angular-routerlink

how to set different color to routerLink , on Chrome its white is same as background so it's text is not visible.

```
 <div class="slds-truncate " style="width: 45ch;overflow: hidden;">
                    <span title={{form.title}}><a routerLink="/form/{{form.id}}/edit"  routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >{{form.title}}</a></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: have you tried somthing?

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the Active Links?

Comment: No, i want to change the color of listed titles which are currently appears white on chrome, blue (#0070d2) on IE

Answer (score 1):

Solved by setting `style="color: #0070d2"` to

```
 <div class="slds-truncate " style="width: 45ch;overflow: hidden;">
                    <span title={{form.title}}><a routerLink="/form/{{form.id}}/edit"  routerLinkActive="router-link-active" style="color: #0070d2">{{form.title}}</a></span>
     </div>
```